# Where do I put license info (.licx) in a .NET Core application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, remobjects

I have created a .NET Core 2.1 class library as a data layer for a .NET Core 2.1 MVC website.  I am using some controls from a company called RemObjects and when I compile I get this message

> .net core LicenseException: No valid license has been found for the type RemObjects.DataAbstract.BaseDataAdapter

I have a license. Normally I would add it to the projects Properties folder but there is not a Properties folder in the project.  I am sure there is a simple explanation but Google has not revealed it.  This is my 1st .NET Core project so go easy on me.

Comment: Have you tried to just include it as an embedded resource?

Comment: You are correct I added it as an embedded resource and it work perfect!  Not sure how to mark this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not much difference where exactly in your project you'll put the licenses.licx file as long as it is contained in the project and has its BuildAction set to EmbeddedResource.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the `Properties` folder if it's required to put the licence file in there. This will absolutely not affect how your class library works.

Comment: Tried this too.  It it did allow for that adding of the folder.  However it was the embedded resource comment that made it work.  Thank for the input.